# SSIS Dynamic Mapping column

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm little new to SSIS and I have a need to import some flat files into SQL tables in the same structure. 
(Assume the table is already exist in the same structure and table name and flat file name is same)
I thought to create a generic package (sql 2014) to import all those file by looping through a folder. 
I try to create a data flow task in  a foreach loop container in the data flow task I dropped a flat file source and ADO.Net destination . 
I have set the file source to a variable so that every time it loops through it get the new file. similarly for the ADO.net table name I set it to a the variable so that each time it select a different table according to the file name.

since both source column names and destination column names are same I assume it will map the columns automatically.

but with a simple map it didn't let me to run the package  so added a column on the source and selected a table and mapped it.

when I run the package I assumed it will automatically re map everything.
but for the first file it ran but second file it failed complaining with map issues.

can some one let me know whether this is achievable by doing some dynamic mapping?? or using any other way.

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks
Ned

Comment: Yes, a lot of people have had the same thought, and no, it cannot be done.   SSIS packages cannot perform dynamic mapping in this way.   The closest thing to it is dynamically creating SSIS packages according to the files you want to import.

Comment: is the structure of all the files same?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately the structure is not same for all of those file. but there is a table exists in destination with the same structure of the file . I'm wondering whether a generic package will do this